# Detox Substring Match Using by.text

Tags: xcode, react-native, testing, jestjs, detox

I'm trying to select an element by text, but the actual text changes because it has the current time stamp in it. Is there is way to select it without doing a substring search on getAttributes()? I can't use getAttributes because we will also be testing on android.

**The select I'm using:**

`await expect(element(by.text("James has initiated the chatbot: ShallowFaqChatbot"))).toBeVisible();`

**The element:**

```
  {
      hittable: true,
      activationPoint: { x: 153.5, y: 14.75 },
      normalizedActivationPoint: { x: 0.5, y: 0.5 },
      elementFrame: { y: 9, x: 9, width: 307, height: 29.5 },
      enabled: true,
      elementBounds: { y: 0, x: 0, width: 307, height: 29.5 },
      layer: '<CALayer: 0x600002b907c0>',
      safeAreaInsets: { right: 0, top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0 },
      visible: true,
      elementSafeBounds: { y: 0, x: 0, width: 307, height: 29.5 },
      label: 'James has initiated the chatbot: ShallowFaqChatbot - 11:08 am',
      className: 'RCTTextView',
      frame: { y: 473, x: 34, width: 307, height: 29.5 },
      text: 'James has initiated the chatbot: ShallowFaqChatbot - 11:08 am'
  }
```

You can see that it has the attribute text with the text I'm looking for, however detox is unable to grab it because of the " - 11:08 am".

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, Detox doesn't support Regex matchers: https://github.com/wix/Detox/issues/1441.

The easiest fix here would be adding a `testID` to the element and matching on that.

```
await expect(element(by.id("James has initiated the chatbot: ShallowFaqChatbot"))).toBeVisible();
```

You would not need to use `.and` to do this match. Not an ideal solution, but since `testID` would be hidden away, this should be a working solution for your case.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [detox "and" matcher](https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/master/docs/APIRef.Matchers.md#andmatcher)

For this you'll have to set your element's [testID](https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/master/docs/Introduction.WritingFirstTest.md#step-3-add-testids-to-your-app-to-assist-in-matching-elements).
Now, let's suppose your element's `testID` is `super_text_field`

If you want to check that this element contains a specific text like "something" you can use the following workaround:

```
await expect(element(by.id('super_text_field').and(by.text('something')))).toBeVisible()
```

Of course this workaround has its limitations and assumptions, but I hope it works for your case!

Comment: The problem is that by.text will still do an exact match, so using the 'and' matcher with an by.id element won't help.

Comment: I think pattern matching is not possible with detox unfortunately :(
Instead, you can try the following workarounds:

(1)  You can refactor your component into two smaller ones, and extract this "time"-part into the second one. Make sure the first one has a `testID`. Then you can check that the first one has the text you want it to.

(2) Try to ensure that the "time"-part is fixed. I'm pretty sure you can control it, so try ensuring that it's set to "21:37" for example. Then you will be able to do full text match